# Django what is the logic behind creating in-app users the same way as admin users?

Tags: python, django

I was looking into how to create in-app users in Django by leveraging their auth system, and I founds this part of their docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

Personally, I do not like this approach because of three reasons:

- an in-app user will still have an empty permissions field. This is a bit scary, what if I misconfigure something? That could enable access to an in-app user to the admin panel.
- while both in-app user and admin panel users are similar in some aspects, they belong in two different worlds. To me, it would make more sense to have the auth system more flexible, and be able to use it with any kind of model, keeping the admin users separate from in-app users.
- having a separate model just to add more fields is an unnecessary overhead.

But then, I am sure there are also some good reasons for this approach or maybe I am wrong and this is not the actual recommended approach. Any views on this?